# inserting a try again feature with function c++

Tags: c++, function

I am a first year college student struggling to put a try again feature in my program.

The program's output is supposed to make the user choose between square, cube and double the integer that is entered and then at the end of the program, it will ask the user if it wants to try again or to end the program.

The whole program seems to be working fine, the only issue I am having trouble with is how to put /allow user to try again.

This is what I got so far.

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int square(int num);
int cube (int num);
int doublee (int num);
int operation();


 main (){
        
     operation();
     
    char endchoice;
    cout << "Try again ? \n";
    cin >> endchoice;
    
    switch (endchoice){
        case 'Y': case 'y':
            operation();
            break;
            
        default :
            cout<<"End.";
            break;
    }
    
    //return 0;
}
    

    
int operation(){
    
    cout << "========= Main Menu ==========\n";
    cout << "[S/s] -  Square\n";
    cout << "[C/C] -  Cube\n";
    cout << "[D/d] -  Double\n";
    cout << "==============================\n";
    
    int  num;
    char choice;
    cout << " Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    
    cout << " Enter an Integer Number: ";
    cin >> num;
    
    
    switch (choice){
        
        case 'S': case 's':
            square(num);
            break;
        
        case 'C': case 'c':
            cube (num);
            break;
        
        case 'D': case 'd':
            doublee (num);
            break;
            
        default :
            cout << "Choice Invalid.";
            break;
    }
    
}

int square (int num){
    
    cout << " The square of " << num << " is: " <<num*num;
    
}

int cube (int num){
    cout << " The cube of " << num << " is: " <<num*num*num;
}

int doublee (int num){
    cout << " The double of " << num << " is: " <<num*2;
}
```

Comment: You need some kind of loop.

Comment: What kind of loops do you know already?

Comment: If you're still struggling with the basics, it can be helpful to make a smaller test program to try a concept. In this case, you could just have a "enter anything" and a "try again" if the user pressed return without entering anything. Bonus: if that still does not work, you have a minimal example to post to StackOverflow.

Comment: we have already learned the do while, while and the for loop.

Comment: And which kind of loop do you think could help you here?

Comment: while loop maybe?

Comment: Good guess. You are running the loop as long as the user enters `y` and your break condition of your loop is any other character. Try to implement this

Comment: You obviously learned about functions, since you have them already in your program.  Thus `while (keep_going()) { operation(); }` -- and `keep_going` returns `true` if the user wants to keep going, or `false` otherwise.  Separating the logic into a function makes it much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `while` or `do-while` loop. Your `main` could look like this (`main` must return `int` by the way):

```
int main() {
    do {
        show_main_menu_and_process_user_input();
    } while(user_wants_to_start_from_the_beginning());
}
```

I'll leave it to you to implement those two functions. The first simply contains the code you already have, while the second asks the user whether they want to start over and returns `true` when the answer was yes.